# Is it safe to run upgrade with Pinned Applications in Synaptic

Tags: upgrade

I have firefox, thunderbird, thunderbird-locale-en, thunderbird-locale-en-us, xul-ext-calendar-timezones, xul-ext-gdata-provider and xul-ext-lightning pinned in Synaptic.

When I run apt-get upgrade. I get the following

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  boot-repair boot-sav darktable firefox libvlc5 libvlccore5 thunderbird thunderbird-locale-en
  thunderbird-locale-en-us vlc vlc-data vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse
  xul-ext-calendar-timezones xul-ext-gdata-provider xul-ext-lightning
17 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 53.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 606 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Are these packages really going to be upgraded?

[image: show lock]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they are going be upgraded.

You have to hold them with dpkg:

```
echo <package> hold | dpkg --set-selections
```

[Reference: Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto#Introduction_to_Holding_Packages)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. This would normally be the case but as you can see. They are LOCKED!

Comment: That lock is ignored by apt-get. If it says they will be upgraded, then they will be upgraded. You can try that with `apt-get upgrade -s` that just simulate the action.

Comment: `apt-get upgrade -s` lists the package name and version

Comment: Not only that, it performs a full simulation of the upgrading. So if it says that it will install that packages, then without the `-s` they will be upgraded.