# Do Not Uninstall Flag on Apt?

Tags: apt, package-management

Does the Debian/Ubuntu package infrastructure has some way of marking packages so that they never get uninstalled, no matter the pinning of other packages?

My problem is that, sometimes, packages installed by Puppet (coming from non-standard repositories, of course) cause other packages to get uninstalled -- in particular, openssh-{server,client}.

The way this happens is that package A and B depend on different versions of package C. If A is installed and one asks to install B, then the version of C changes. The new version of C is incompatible with A, so A gets uninstalled.

The funny thing is that the process is then reversed, as, on the next run, Puppet notices that A is not installed and tries to install it.

So, basically, I want to make sure A *never* gets uninstalled, which would prevent B from getting installed. That would be reported as an error, making me aware of the issue.

If anyone cares, Puppet uses the following command to install packages:

```
/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install <package>
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/116180/46312 you have to hold the pinned application

Answer (score 3):

You need to "hold" the packages so that `apt-get upgrade` never *removes them as part of upgrading to a newer version.*

`echo "package-name hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections`

However, note that explicitly doing an `apt-get install package-name` WILL override the hold, while an `apt-get remove package-name` WILL uninstall it.

If you pin it to a specific version with a priority of 1001 or greater, even `apt-get install` will NOT upgrade it, but it can still be removed.

Comment: Do I need to go through `dpkg`? Isn't there a configuration file for it? Also, would `hold` prevent them from being updated by unattended-upgrades?

Comment: It's highly recommended you NOT mess with the `dpkg` config files themselves. If you want GUI you can also go Synaptic and use right-click "lock this package", but I have seen some reports that the lock isn't obeyed.

Comment: Hold should prevent them from being upgraded. Only an explicit `apt-get install held-package` will override it.

Comment: Actually, I want text files updated through Puppet. GUI is the farthest thing from what I want. However, I saw that the packages that got inadvertently removed seemed to be in `HOLD` already, so I'm now suspicious of this method. Besides, I want them updated as usual, just not removed (particularly given their sensitivity to security issues).

Comment: You need to explain your update scenario and/or give more details. Packages are not removed unless they are being upgraded or there is a conflict; you have to `apt-get autoremove` them.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question with more details. If there's anything else you think is relevant, I'll be happy to provide.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I'll look at this after I get back from work this evening.

Answer (score 1):

This can probably be solved by adding the this to apt.conf[.d]:

```
Aptitude::Always-Use-Safe-Resolver "true";
```

And to site.pp in puppet:

```
Package { provider => 'aptitude' }
```

Haven't tested that properly yet though.

Comment: Actually, just noticed the APT::Get::Remove option to apt-get, should solve it as well. Command line is --no-remove.

Comment: That's a general flag, isn't it? I want to mark specific packages.